# How can I put a transition when my overlay is opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on, when I click on an element, an overlay is opened with a content inside, but I'd like to add a transition effect to it.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
(function($)
{
    $('.overlay-trigger').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#expose-mask').css({'display': 'inherit'}).fadeIn(function()
        {
            $('.overlay-box').css({'display': 'inherit'});
        });
    });
    $('#expose-mask, .overlay-box').css({'display': 'none'});
    $('.overlay-box-closer, #expose-mask').click(function()
    {
        $('.overlay-box, #expose-mask').css({'display': 'none'});
        $('#expose-mask');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

`.overlay-trigger` class means the activator of the overlay when I click on an element, `#expose-mask` means the background when the overlay is opened and the `.overlay-box` class means the content inside the `#expose-mask` id when it is open.

I'd like something like this, on this site: http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

I'd like to have the "Slide in (bottom)" effect.

I don't use the same code as on this site, so I don't know how. Here's my HTML code:

```
<a id="help" class="overlay-trigger" href="help.php">Help</a>
<div class="overlay-box">
<div class="overlay-box-container">
    <span class="overlay-box-closer" title="Close the overlay"></span>
    <h1 class="big-title">Help</h1>
    <p>Your privacy is important to us. To better protect your privacy we provide this notice explaining our online information practices and the choices you can make about the way your information is collected and used. To make this notice easy to find, we make it available in our footer and at every point where personally identifiable information may be requested.Log files are maintained and analysed of all requests for files on this website's web servers. Log files do not capture personal information but do capture the user's IP address, which is automatically recognised by our web servers.</p>
</div>
```

my CSS code:

```
.overlay-box
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    top: 35%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 4;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 7px;
}

.overlay-box-container
{
    margin: 20px;
}

.overlay-box-closer:before
{
    content: "\f00d";
    position: absolute;
    top: -21px;
    right: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#expose-mask
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Live preview here: http://nextgenfocus.com/test1/ Click the "Help" text in the footer to open the overlay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
(function($)
{
    $('.overlay-trigger').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#expose-mask').show();
        $('.overlay-box').slideDown("slow");        
    });
    $('#expose-mask, .overlay-box').hide();

    $('.overlay-box-closer, #expose-mask').click(function()
    {
        $('.overlay-box, #expose-mask').hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, but no change: http://screencast.com/t/WaW3aY0cAimK :/ I'd like have something like this: http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Comment: Maybe something is different in your code, I have an animation : http://jsfiddle.net/Maryyy/xguvhd5a/.

Comment: Yes, but I don't work something like this, dude. I want a transition like on this site: http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Answer (score 0):

css transition::

```
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
```

css animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.fadeInUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

add to your `.overlay-box`:

```
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: flash;
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
-moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
-moz-animation-duration: 1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-name: fadeInUp;
animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Comment: The result is exactly same. :/

Comment: sorry i wrong something, see above, i edited my post.

Comment: There is still no change. :/ http://screencast.com/t/zMteb86RI I'd like have something like this: http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Comment: to deploy your popup with animation, not so?

Comment: Yes, but normally I did not need it. It's just that there is something missing and I do not know what.

Comment: How can I have exactly that effect please? http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ The Slide in (bottom) effect.